# Can my work see my contacts on private MSN

Tags: vpn

new to vpn. My work has just started using a vpn and I work from home connected to it. After I finished work I mistakenly signed into my private MSN whilst still connected to the vpn. For private reasons I would rather some work mates didn't know who was on my private MSN. Basically do my work now have the info at hand of who my contacts are on private MSN?

Sorry for the lack of info regarding the vpn and thank you in advance for any replies.

Dave

Answer (score 1):

It's possible...not nearly enough information to know for sure.  I don't believe you contact list is sent across the wire in it's totality.  But messages sent would be easily sniffed depending on network configuration.  Also, the is available notification could be sniffed.  MSN messenger, at least when I was supporting it, would fall back to port 80 if the "high" port was blocked.  I wouldn't worry about it horribly, but then I assume anything I do on a computer is public domain.

Comment: And I believe your contact list is downloaded to your machine as an XML file in your app settings folder, which may also be in clear text.